# How to search in Intellij when keymap=eclipse?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've setup keymap=eclipse in IntelliJ, however I am not getting to understand how to perform search full text and wildcard search in file or in while project?

Comment: You mean CTRL+ALF+F?

Comment: nope its not working

Comment: What is "wildcard search"? Do you mean "regex search" toggle: https://i.imgur.com/4j8cQvX.png ? 

 And what is "search full text" is it "Find in files" action? YOu may check the shortcut in keymap:  https://i.imgur.com/bhpuR2E.png